# How does RedisCacheManager and Redis manage cache names?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

How does Redis manage cache names as used by the `getCache("name")` method in the `org.springframework.cache.CacheManager` interface that belongs to the Spring Framework?

I have done a few tests here and could not take any conclusions neither I found any documentation to clarify my question.

I have a simple Spring Boot application that connects to Redis and issues a few commands.

Redis configuration:

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class RedisCacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer redisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer() {
        return (builder) -> {
            Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> config = new HashMap<>();

            RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfig = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
              .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(storage.getTtl()))
              .disableCachingNullValues();
            cacheConfig.usePrefix();
            config.put("channel", cacheConfig);
            builder.withInitialCacheConfigurations(config);
        };
    }
}
```

Test Case:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class RedisCacheServiceIT {

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private RedisCacheManager cacheManager;

    @Test
    void testCache() {
        var cache = cacheManager.getCache("cache1");
        cache.put("key1", "value1");
        cache.put("key2", "value2");

        var cachedVal = cache.get("key1", String.class);
        assertEquals("value1", cachedVal);

        cache = cacheManager.getCache("channel");
        cache.put("xyz", "123");

        cachedVal = cache.get("xyz", String.class);
        assertEquals("123", cachedVal);

        redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("my_cache::xpto", "1234");
    }

    @Test
    void testCacheNames() {
        var names = cacheManager.getCacheNames();
        names.forEach(n -> System.out.println("cache: " + n));
    }
}
```

The above test will print the following line:

- cache: cache1
- cache: channel

Even if I manually delete all keys on Redis, next time I run only the test case `testCacheNames()` without adding any keys to the cache, it also prints the same cache names.

Where does Redis store those cache names? I could not find using a Redis client (i.e. RedisInsight).

Also why "my_cache" was not listed as a cache name as well?

Answer (score 1):

I got it! I was so naive... Sorry, but I have to answer my own question tho. The `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` will keep in memory all caches configured in the `RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer`  Bean configuration (see method `redisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer()`). And also every time the code calls `cacheManager.getCache(name)` will also store it in memory. So whenever I call `cacheManager.getCacheNames()` it will return all caches added to it. I though it was getting this data from Redis service.

Comment: I tried calling `cacheManager.getCache(name)` in my bean configuration - that runs during startup. Yet when later on, a controller action calls `cacheManager.getCacheNames()` so that I can then go through and clear each of the caches, no names are returned!
It's only if methods with the `@Cachable` annotation have been called that the names are available.
As I know the names of the caches, I've done a workaround whereby I supply these names if they don't come back from `cacheManager.getCacheNames()` - but it's a bit hacky.